# ImageNew toBase64 encoding issue with loss of quality in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have been having problems with toBase64() for awhile. I am hoping someone can tell me why CF toBase64() seems to lost something i.e. in my example it reduces the quality of an image.

I have a solution (see last code example below), but I hate not understanding why and would love to solve this is CF.

If anyone would be so kind to run the code below, you would then see that after toBase64 conversion the image quality is bad. Nothing major, but it does not look as good after the encoding. If you have never noticed, then try it, you will see what I mean.

Does anyone know why, or how to solve this in CF?

```
<!--- EXAMPLE 1 --->

<!--- GET IMAGE - --->
<cfset image = ImageNew("test.png")>
<!--- BEFORE GOOD--->
<cfimage action="writeToBrowser" source="#image#" >
 <cfset image = toBinary(toBase64(image)) />
 <!--- AFTER --->
<cfimage action="writeToBrowser" source="#image#" >
```

---

```
<!--- Example 2 --->
<cfset image = ImageNew("test.png")>
<cfset FileWrite(expandPath('./converted.image'),toBinary(toBase64(image))) />
<!--- without any cfimage processing, the outputted file is a JPEG --->
```

My solution was to use a java add-on and everything seemed ok but for reasons I won't go into here not something I can do live.

```
image = createObject("java","it.sauronsoftware.base64.Base64").encode(image);
 toBinary(image );
```

Sample image output of code above can be found here: http://i56.tinypic.com/29fwiq.png
First is before toBase64 second is after, you can see the image has lost a bit of quality after toBase64 function on the second output.

**Update:** As pointed out by Peter, the issue seems to be with the automatic output/conversion code within the ImageObject to provide the binary output for the toBase64 function to encode.

**Update** I have submitted this as a bug in CF 9.0.1, please vote for bug 3177303
https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3177303

Comment: See examples outputs here: http://i56.tinypic.com/29fwiq.png PS as I pointed out to Shawn below, this is not related to "quality" attribute and I only used cfimage in my example for demonstration.  The issue seems to be with CF's implementation of toBase64.

Comment: This makes no sense, but you're right that the bug is in the `toBase64` function - i.e. `toBase64(ImageObject)` results in a JPEG file, even when the original was a PNG. This should be reported at [cfbugs.adobe.com](http://cfbugs.adobe.com)

Comment: I've added another example that shows this isn't related to cfimage (although the default format for that is PNG anyway).

Comment: Bah, I can't re-word my initial comment here - the bug likely _isn't_ in toBase64 itself, but in the automatic output/conversion code within the ImageObject to provide the binary output for the `toBase64` function to encode. As [Henry's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050555/tobase64-encoding-issue-with-loss-of-quality-in-coldfusion#8055184) shows, using imageGetBlob to correctly extract the data first removes the problem.

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to file this as a bug or enhancement and have Adobe changes the current behaviour in future version, since most ppl who want to use toBase64(image) wants the actual blob.

Comment: Yep, I stand by it being a bug. An image should never automatically switch to a lower quality format. Such a change should always be a deliberate/clear action.

Comment: Hi, I am not 100% sure what I am filing as a bug, to me this is a bug and everything points to the CF Image Object (imageNew). Henry's solution toBase64(imageGetBlob(myImg)) only works when the initial image is a png etc. However, jpg still has the same issue with reduction of quality regardless.

Comment: I have submitted this as a bug in CF 9.0.1 please vote: Bug 3177303

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `toBase64(imageGetBlob(myImg))`

see: http://blog.dkferguson.com/index.cfm/2010/4/27/All-your-base64-are-not-equal

Comment: This works for my tests - seems like `ImageGetBlob` correctly extracts the PNG data, so `toBase64` is then converting the correct data.

Comment: Not my question. :P But yes, I assume Spark will see this and do that.

Comment: You may use `fileReadBinary()` as outlined at the url posted in the answer, if `imageNew()` is still degrading your PNG somehow.

Comment: Thanks so much, my tests locally now show how they should. I use imageNew() function which still shows them badly even with toBase64(imageGetBlob(myImg)). so as you were saying Peter this must be an issue with the cf image object.

Comment: Just one last thing, has anyone tried the same test with a jpg? The quality of the image is worst. imageGetBlob() function only seems to extract the PNG data correct. if the initial image was jpg it's still really bad, if not more so than before the imageGetBlob() fix was added. I can get around this with fileReadBinary (not using cf image object at all) but it seems like more is going on here. I 100% now agree the issue is with imageNew().

Comment: Yes. Cfimage is not perfect. There's imagemagik : faster, stronger

Answer (score 1):

I see no one has mentioned the imageWriteBase64() function that has been in ColdFusion since version 8. I am not sure why.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-796b.html

I have been using it this week for the first time and it seems to be going great. I have not noticed any problems with quality loss.

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#expandPath('./images')#" name="imageDir" type="file" />

<cfloop query="imageDir">
    <cfset ext = listLast(imageDir.name, ".") />
    <cfset name = imageDir.name />
    <cfset imagePath = imageDir.directory & "/" & name />

    <cfset imageFile = imageNew(imagePath) />

    <cfset imageWriteBase64(imageFile,"#expandPath('./base64')#/#name#.txt",ext, true) />   
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I guess the reason is because usually they want to have the base64 string in a variable so that they can embed in `data:` or persist to DB.  Although you can write it and read it back, maybe even to `ram://` for CF9, it's just more hoops to jump through compare to `toBase64(imageGetBlob(myImg))`

Comment: Yes, I need it to be a base64 string to stream. I could write to to ram but cannot afford server resources. Would be interesting to see tho if you displayed a jpg using Jason's example if it would actually give the same results! I didn't even noticed until it was pointed out to me on a high res display! I did some searching a while back and found an old Cf bug that 'could' be related to this issue, tho now it seems more like the object cf creates than the 64 conversion: http://www.webmasterkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/coldfusion-db/4949/CF-Base64-incompatibility-to-a-Java-Base64

Comment: Testing this out, there is a definitive quality loss.  They quality loss may not be visual, but its there, and you can tell by the file size.  Take the original image, then do a write to a new file as a whatever format its supposed to be and you will see the difference in size of the output vs the input.  I did this and it was driving me crazy as to why.  You can also go to any "Image to Base64" website and do an online conversion and see the difference in the Base64 strings.  Try this one [https://www.imgtobase64.com/](https://www.imgtobase64.com/) or any other one you can do a web search.