# How do I create a CF compatible image from a java Buffered Image

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

How do I create a CF compatible image object from a java Buffered Image without the use of CF ImageNew() function?

```
imageCFCObj = createObject("component","imagecfc.image" );
local.img1 = imageCFCObj.readImage("D:\#arguments.directoryPath#");

 // local.img1 now of type java.awt.image.BufferedImage
 // from here how do you create a CF compatible image object?
```

**(Updated to include links)**
So without using CF function ImageNew() (it has [major issue with automatic output/conversion code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050555/imagenew-tobase64-encoding-issue-with-loss-of-quality-in-coldfusion),  see [bug #3177303](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3177303) ) How do you change this using JAVA in CF to a compatible CF image object I can use.

Comment: Check the hotfixes - image stuff get's lots of tweaks in the HFs so you might find a solution for your conversion problem but other than that I think you will need to settle on a "pure Java" solution here and stop trying to bring it back into the CF native tags.

Comment: Thats a shame. Whatever the outcome it has to be a CF compatible object tho :)

Comment: I have all hotfix applied for 9.0.1 already issue with imagenew is still there.

Comment: @Spark - What is the issue you are having with `ImageNew`? Because like Mark suggested, (the normal - and possibly only) path to a CF compatible image is what you are trying to avoid: ie pass the BufferedImage into ImageNew.

Comment: It's not very elagent but you could always just write the Java object to disk and then read it back using CF.

Comment: @Jake I want to try and avoid writing to disk.

Comment: @Leigh there is a major issue with imageNew the issue seems to be with the automatic output/conversion code within the ImageObject to provide the binary output for the toBase64 function to encode. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050555/imagenew-tobase64-encoding-issue-with-loss-of-quality-in-coldfusion/8067729#8067729

Comment: I have submitted this as a bug please vote Bug 3177303. still would love to find a java work around or any other ideas tho in the mean time.

Comment: @Spark - So is the base64 conversion the only problem? Because there may be other ways to grab the image bytes.  I agree with Peter's comment about png's are being converted to jpg (which explains degradation in quality there). But later on you mentioned a problem with `imageGetBlob()` and jpeg's too. I tried a few images but did not observe major degradation. Any chance you have an image that demos the problem with jpegs?

Comment: yes newimage() is only the issue when used with base64 which i need. the main issues comes when i do this toBinary(toBase64(arguments.data)) to display back to the page. if the image is a transparent png the transparent area is turned black. If i knew how to turn the bufferedImage back base64 i think i could avoid using newimage(). "Peter's comment about png's are being converted to jpg" yes all my transparent png come out black.

Comment: toBinary(toBase64(arguments.data)) <-- this is when it gets converted to a jpg from what i can tell.

Comment: Hm.. so Henry's suggestion of using `imageGetBlob` did not resolve that issue? (I cannot test it right now). If not you could try using [`ImageIO.write`](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-bufferedimage-to-byte-in-java/) instead, for BufferedImages. Or possibly the undocumented getImageBytes() method of the CF Image class:  `bytes = yourCFImageObject.getImageBytes("png")`. The latter is what `ImageGetBlob` uses.

Comment: @Leigh no imageGetBlob() did the same thing. getImageBytes not seem before so will try this.

Comment: Variable GETIMAGEBYTES is undefined running 9.0.1 are you sure this exits?

Comment: It is not a variable. It is a method of the internal CF Image class. So you need to create a CF image object first.

Comment: sorry my mistake!    yes it worked!!!!!!    imageNew("D:\wwwroot\imageStore\#arguments.directoryPath#\#arguments.imageName#").getimagebytes("png")

Comment: It works with transparent png's too?

Comment: @Leigh yep worked perfectly with them. thanks so much. can you post as answer so i can accept?

Comment: @Spark - (I do not know if the bug database notifies people of new comments, so ...) But regarding: Re: "`getImageBytes()` is not ideal as all my image are now converted to png" If your image source is a physical file, apply it conditionally (ie only when the extension is *.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(From the comments above, the answer ended up going in a different direction).

As mentioned [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050555/imagenew-tobase64-encoding-issue-with-loss-of-quality-in-coldfusion) using `toBase64(imageObject)` and `imageGetBlob` may result in degradation of image quality because `png` images are converted to `jpg` format. These functions seems to determine the return format incorrectly.

A possible work-around is using the *undocumented* `Image.getImageBytes(format)` method which allows you to specify the output format explicitly.

```
<cfset bytes = yourCFImageObject.getImageBytes("png")>
```